# How to get specific cell from table mysql to Vb.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I need to get a specific data/cell from a table and embed it to a label.text, for example

I have a table named `Student` with columns of `Student_No.`, `Student_Name`, `Student_Age`, `Year` and `Section`. And I need to get a single data/cell from a column but the next code will get the one next to it and so on.

I got a code like this:

```
SELECT col_name  
  FROM table_name  
 WHERE col_name='values'  
 LIMIT 1
```

but it gets the first one and if I change the limit to 2 it gets two...

Comment: Try using LIMIT and Offset like as `SELECT col_name FROM table_name WHERE col_name='values' LIMIT 1,1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should specify the id of the entry you want to get from the table

```
SELECT col_name 
  FROM table_name 
 WHERE col_name='values' 
       AND id = '1' LIMIT 1
```